# Pandas zero-copy MultiIndex / FrozenNDArray creation

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a pandas `DataFrame` from a bunch of numpy `ndarray` without copying anything. The overall objective is to share a huge `DataFrame` between many processes from a shared memory.

Some information on my environment:

- `pandas 0.18.0`
- `numpy 1.10.4`
- `python 3.5`

The function I use to retrieve the underlying data pointer of my `ndarray`s:

```
def ndarray_data_ptr(a):
    return hex(a.__array_interface__['data'][0])
```

#### Problem 1

It seems that pandas does not like `int16` index. It will silently convert them to `int64` and make a copy even though I specifically ask for zero-copy.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> data = np.array([1.23, 4.56, 7.89], dtype=np.dtype(np.float64))
>>> index = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.dtype(np.int16))

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     data=val,
...     index=pd.Index(idx, copy=False),
...     copy=False)

>>> print('data', ndarray_data_ptr(data))
data 0x2322790

>>> print('index', ndarray_data_ptr(index))
index 0x228d680

>>> print('df data', ndarray_data_ptr(df.values))
df data 0x2322790

>>> print('df index', ndarray_data_ptr(df.index.values))
df index 0x218a100
```

**I managed to overcome this issue by explicitely providing the desired `dtype` when creating the `pd.Index`**. It seems to work as expected now, even though the behavior of pandas is not really obvious. I would have expected the default value for `dtype=` of the constructor to be `None` and re-use the `dtype` of the provided `ndarray`. Instead, the default `dtype=` is `object` and the resulting `Index` is coerced to `int64`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     data=data,
...     index=pd.Index(index, copy=False, dtype=index.dtype),
...     copy=False)

>>> print('data', ndarray_data_ptr(data))
data 0x2403780

>>> print('index', ndarray_data_ptr(index))
index 0x1abe930

>>> print('df data', ndarray_data_ptr(df.values))
df data 0x2403780

>>> print('df index', ndarray_data_ptr(df.index.values))
df index 0x1abe930
```

#### Problem 2

The previous example was just a starter. The real `DataFrame` that I want to build actually uses a `MultiIndex`.

```
>>> data = np.array([1.23, 4.56, 7.89], dtype=np.dtype(np.float64))

>>> index_levels = [
>>>     np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.dtype(np.int16)),
>>>     np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype=np.dtype(np.int16)),
>>> ]

>>> index_labels = [
>>>     np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=np.dtype(np.int16)),
>>>     np.array([0, 1, 2], dtype=np.dtype(np.int16)),
>>> ]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
>>>     data=data,
>>>     index=pd.MultiIndex(
>>>         levels=[
>>>             pd.Index(index_levels[0], dtype=index_levels[0].dtype, copy=False),
>>>             pd.Index(index_levels[1], dtype=index_levels[1].dtype, copy=False),
>>>         ],
>>>         labels=[
>>>             pd.core.base.FrozenNDArray(index_labels[0], dtype=index_labels[0].dtype, copy=False),
>>>             pd.core.base.FrozenNDArray(index_labels[1], dtype=index_labels[1].dtype, copy=False),
>>>         ],
>>>         copy=False,
>>>     ),
>>>     copy=False)

>>> print('index level 0', ndarray_data_ptr(index_levels[0]))
index level 0 0x24adf70

>>> print('index level 1', ndarray_data_ptr(index_levels[1]))
index level 1 0x24a7d90

>>> print('index label 0', ndarray_data_ptr(index_labels[0]))
index label 0 0x1400b10

>>> print('index label 1', ndarray_data_ptr(index_labels[1]))
index label 1 0x25d34f0

>>> print('df index level 0', ndarray_data_ptr(df.index.levels[0].values))
df index level 0 0x24adf70

>>> print('df index level 1', ndarray_data_ptr(df.index.levels[1].values))
df index level 1 0x24a7d90

>>> print('df index label 0', ndarray_data_ptr(df.index.labels[0]))
df index label 0 0x24c0ad0

>>> print('df index label 1', ndarray_data_ptr(df.index.labels[1]))
df index label 1 0x24c0ad0
```

The index **levels** were properly re-used without copy, whereas the index **labels** were copied. Actually, I noticed that the labels are not `pd.Index` but pandas instead uses `pd.core.base.FrozenNDArray` instances, so I tried to trick them with the same technique used in *Problem 1* but this is apparently not enough.

Even the `dtype` of the `FrozenNDArray` were coerced to `int8` when building the `MultiIndex`.

```
>>> df.index.levels[0]
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int16')

>>> df.index.levels[1]
Int64Index([4, 5, 6], dtype='int16')

>>> df.index.labels[0]
FrozenNDArray([0, 1, 2], dtype='int8')

>>> df.index.labels[1]
FrozenNDArray([0, 1, 2], dtype='int8')
```

I spent quite a lot of time figuring out how to prevent this `dtype` coercion in the case of `MultiIndex`, but I still cannot figure out how.

In my real world problem, the overall `DataFrame` is ~40GB and the index labels account for ~300MB. I would like to prevent this unnecessary per-process memory overhead.

If anyone managed to build pandas `DataFrame`s from shared memory, or just create `MultiIndex` without any copy, I would really like to benefit from your experience.

Comment: You got no upvotes for 5 years for something that is extremely valuable information. Looks like people just do not care about optimization. Thank you, i find this very useful!

Comment: @rokaskupstys I managed to expose read only dataframes through shared memory in the end, and ended up just duplicating the indices per process.